# Xcode forcing the UIView size to be same as a UIContainerView when running a segue

Tags: xcode, uistoryboardsegue, xcode-storyboard

I have the following view hierarchy in my storyboard

```
UIViewController
-UIView
--UIContainerView
---UITableViewController
----UITableView

      |
  push segue
      |
      ﹀
UIViewController
-UIView
```

That container view with the table view takes about 1/3 of the screen. I want to trigger a segue into a whole new UIViewController from a given table row. When I place the new UIViewController onto the storyboard and hook up the push segue from the table view, Xcode resizes the target UIView to be the same size as the container and the UITableViewController are (1/3 of the screen). However, when you run the code and enter the segue, the 'end' view is fullscreen as it should.

This Xcode's resizing makes it impossible to layout the interface for the 'end' view in Xcode. If this is not a bug on Xcode what would be the proper way to hook up this segue and still be able to layout the interface in storyboard?